# Can Microsoft Edge be launched in “Private Mode” through cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, browser, powershell, microsoft-edge

Can Microsoft-Edge be launched in "Private Mode" through the command line?

I'm using this shell command to launch it with a specific URL:

```
start microsoft-edge:www.google.com
```

Is there some kind of flag to lauch Edge in "Private Mode"?

I would like to run in in c#, something like:

```
Process.Start("microsoft-edge:www.google.com", "-privateMode");
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be possible at this point. It is a feature that is requested however: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9245247-inprivate-command-line-switch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32308174

Answer (score 5):

For the newer Chromium-based Microsoft Edge, use this command:

```
start msedge.exe https://google.com -inPrivate
```

Comment: Is this for the new Chromium based Edge?

Comment: @music2myear - Chromium

Answer (score 2):

Two years later, we have found a solution:

`%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /c start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge -private http:\\google.com`

Comment: Why bother specifying a full path for ``cmd``?  Do you need to use backslashes in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at present, however - something like the following in powershelkl may work for you:

```
& cmd /c start microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com
start-sleep -Seconds 5
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Microsoft Edge")

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("+^(p)")
```

You can create a shortcut to execute this (PowerShell.exe -File C:\users\me\desktop\thisscript.ps1) and you will have a shortcut to launch in private mode

Answer (score 0):

Try `msedge.exe https://google.com -inPrivate` without `start` at the beginning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).